# Other IDs not triggered when i trigger change event on daterangepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom-events

When i triggered change event on datepicker it works fine but the change event of others IDs not triggered.
But when i put my daterange id to the end, change event works fine for all IDs but not for date range.
I want to use this change event works fine for all IDs including daterange picker.

```
 $(document).on('change', '#sell_list_filter_date_range', '#sell_list_filter_location_id, #sell_list_filter_customer_id, #sell_list_filter_payment_status, #created_by, #sales_cmsn_agnt, #service_staffs', function () {
         // here change event works fine for only daterange  
       
        });

$(document).on('change', '#sell_list_filter_location_id, #sell_list_filter_customer_id, #sell_list_filter_payment_status, #created_by, #sales_cmsn_agnt, #service_staffs','#sell_list_filter_date_range', function () {
             // here change event works fine for all IDs instead for Date range id
           
            });
```

Comment: why not use a general `class` and attach the listener on it?

Comment: help me to do this.

Comment: Posted an answer @ZAIN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the onchange event has the same logic for every dropdown, you can just use a general `class` as a selector to avoid confusions and unnecessary code on your work. You can do this by adding `classnames` on every dropdown that you want to attach the listener to.

```
<select class="listen" id="id-here">
  ...
</select>
<select class="listen" id="some-unique-id-here">
  ...
</select>
```

You can then attach the listener on `change`

```
$(function(){
  $('.listen').on('change', function(){
     /* 
      Now regardless of the dropdown's id, 
      you can now refer to the element by using $(this)  
     */

     var value = $(this).val();
     alert(value);

  })

})
```